# Get the value discarding the marker in JavaScript by substring

Tags: javascript

In an implementation I am fetching list of values by doing substring.
For example below are list of values:

```
First list item = 'itemno1',second list item = 'itemno2',third list item = 'itemno3 ****disabled****'.
```

I am using a marker `disabled` to identify the value as a disabled one. So, when the user
adding a value, I am just appending a space and then appending the marker `disabled` after that. But while updating I want to discard the marker and only get the value.

So, I am using the function below:

```
function GetAppropriateListValue(listVal) {
    return listVal.substring(0, Math.max(0, listVal.lastIndexOf(" ")) || Infinity);
}
```

The function above discards the rest of characters after the first space character.

But, in some other scenario, user can add an item with multiple spaces.

```
'itemno10 itemno10 ****disabled****'
```

Here I need to get the value after discarding the marker `****disabled****`

How can I achieve this in JavaScript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'itemno10 itemno10 *disabled*'
str = str.replace('*disabled*',""); // returns 'itemno10 itemno10 '
```

Comment: thanks..i also thought the same way to replace.But is there any way by doing substring ? But it may not necessary,only want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty but if you want a substring then

```
var s='itemno10 itemno10 *****disabled****';
var t='itemno11 itemno11';
s = s.slice(0,(s.indexOf(' *')!== -1)? s.indexOf(' *'):undefined);
t = t.slice(0,(t.indexOf(' *')!== -1)? t.indexOf(' *'):undefined);
alert(s + " " + t);
```